# Concat two colums to find duplicates and then select the latest date

Tags: mysql

So my table has:
column1, column2, column3 & datetime

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column1 = :column1
CONCAT column1 & column2 (column1NRcolumn2) to get a string to search for duplicates.
SELECT 1 column1_column2 WHERE datetime is highest
```

What i want is to combine two cells to create a new temponary column. (column1NRcolumn2)

Then i want to look for duplicates and then select the latest column1NRcolum2 WHERE datetime is highest/latest

How can i manage this?

Comment: `where concat(colum1, column2) = ?` doesn't work? This isn't a PHP question. Sample data would be useful so we can actually test what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery for concatenated  columns having count > 1 and join to your table for max datetime

```
select  t.my_concat, max(m.datetime)
from mytable m
inner join (
  SELECT concat(column1,column2)  my_concat
  FROM mytable 
  group by  concat(column1,column2)  
  having count(*)>1 
) t 
group by  t.my_concat
```

and if you need  thre related  mytable columns  you need  a join on the max datetime

```
select  m2.*
from mytable m2
inner join
(
  select  t.my_concat, max(m.datetime) max_datetime
  from mytable m
  inner join (
    SELECT concat(column1,column2)  my_concat
    FROM mytable 
    group by  concat(column1,column2)  
    having count(*)>1 
  ) t 
  group by  t.my_concat  
) t2 on t2.my_concat = m2. concat(column1,column2)   
    and  t.max_datetime = m2.datetime
```

Comment: This seems to work, but where should i put in other columns i like to select? The result of this will print "my_concat" but i also like to print column3 and column4 etc from that SELECT

Comment: I did also notice that i got only one result..(one row). I need to select all column1 that are equal to a given number (etc. 1234) This will give me a list with multiple rows.. after that i need to sort out duplicates by concat column1 & column2.

Comment: @BjörnC   .. SO is not a coding service .. but an question/answer  site ..  based on your OP  i think ia already asnswer  at your question  ..  if you have more  ..  you should  (if right ) mark the right answer  and post a new well documented, clear and complete new question --

Comment: .. post  a new question with  a clear data sample ..  and the expctedc result  as tabular text   (not only code ..)  and comment me the link for the new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416684/how-to-combine-two-cells-to-find-find-duplicates-and-then-list-only-the-latest-o  The new question!