# How to combine two cells to find find duplicates and then list only the latest one?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named element_location.
The table have 4 columns: obj_nr, el_nr, location & date_scanned

The table could look like this:

```
id    obj_nr    el_nr    location    date_scanned
1      1234      1        A           2019-01-01
2      1234      2        A           2019-01-02
3      1234      1        A           2019-01-03
```

Now I'd like to make a SELECT where I combine `obj_nr` & `el_nr` to find my duplicates. (Row 1 & 3) In the SELECT I only want to print the latest row. I get the latest by the column `date_scanned`.

How can I make a select that gives me all data from row 2 & 3. (Leaving row 1 because row 3 has same `obj_nr` & `el_nr` and a newer date?

I've tried:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(obj_nr, el_nr), obj_nr, el_nr, location, date_scanned 
    FROM element_location 
    WHERE obj_nr = :obj_nr 
    ORDER BY date_scanned DESC";
```

Comment: Not understanding the titel/question in combination with the expected result description because of contradictions.. Sounds to me you simply want the lastest record per (obj_nr, el_nr) group as `2      1234      2        A           2019-01-02` is never duplicated?

Comment: Sorry @RaymondNijland I'm having a hard time to explain what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking to your sample  seems you need

```
select max(id) id , obj_nr, el_nr, location, max(date_scanned)
from  my_table 
group by  obj_nr,  el_nr, location
```

or if you dont't mind for location but only for max date_scanned

```
select  m2.id, m2.obj_nr, m2.el_nr ,  m2.location,   m2.date_scanned
from  my_table m2
from  (
  select  obj_nr,  el_nr, max(date_scanned) max_date 
  from my_table  
  group by  obj_nr,    el_nr
) t ON  t.obj_nr = m2.obj_nr and t.el_nr = m2.el_nr and t. = m2.date_scanned
```

Comment: Works, i had to put in my WHERE clause. Thank you. But i don't understand why "location" is in the group by?!

Comment: answer  updated ..  avoiding location  ..  (depend  by the columns you use for eval a duplicated ..)  ..  with all these sample  .. i think the tecnique is clear ..  using a subquery for group the value you need  for match

Comment: @BjörnC if you only need to know with location `A` or the table only is filled with location `A` you can optimize the first query from scaisEdge as https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jqFXKDzrR6fx7khPqBwjRd/4 as it is not clear if you have more locations..